# Pass a parameter to the whole Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 4.3.1 and I want to pass a string to the whole Angular application, and I cannot find any useful solution for that.

Now I managed to create something, that I see as a dirty workaround.

First of all -> simple architecture overview:

I have a default index.html with

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

I added script tag, that loads an external JS file.

```
<script src="http://external.com/external.js"></script>
```

And I also have a small script which gets some generic data via this external.js.

Now I need to pass this data to a service in angular, and I didn't find any nice solution, so this is what I do:

I created a component with a not visible **input** and a not visible **button**.
Via

```
[(ngModel)]=
```

**input** is bound to a member of that component. And **button** got an event on click ->

```
(click)="setData($event)"
```

When the SPA is loaded, my script searches for that **input** field, places data inside of it, and simulates a click on a **button**.

Well, this is very very ugly, but it works.

So, is there any nice solution for this problem? May be I am thinking in wrond direction?

**UPDATE:**
I managed to pass data over an parameter of a route, which is much better solution.
But I am still not sure, if it is a most apropriate solution, since this data could be *too long*.

Lets assume, that *security* is not an issue here.

Comment: Can you give more detail please? There are tons of ways to get a string data to a service. You can make http requests, use pre-defined config files/variables etc.

Comment: Well, I have a angular class, which happens to be a "service", but any class would be fine for me as a "data receiver".
An http request seems not to be apropriate, since it is a SPA.
A config file seems also not to be apropriate too, sinse this "data" is dynamic.

Comment: No what I don't understand is, if you can "get" this data externally why don't you use this script internally? How is this external.js generating the data you need? Can't you use it inside your service?

Comment: Well, that was my intention, but, I didn't find a way to load a javascript file from withhin of a typescript to be used by the typescript class, and angular needs to compile all its files before deploy anyway, so this external js file needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: So why don't you have that file at compile time?

Comment: This is very uncommon situation you are in, and your solution (as you told yourself) isn't the prettiest

Comment: And in general, you should avoid executinig any external code. Either use HTTP to retrieve some data or use a config file that is loaded when application starts

Comment: When it is data, maybe you can load (http get request) for a json file. A whole js-File is very dangerous to load and execute.

Comment: Well, if i say "import * as e from 'http://external.com/external.js'", angular does not want to load it :(

Comment: And there is a very good reason for why it doesn't want to do that - security! Why that js file is not packaged and can't be retrieved as any other dependency (like angular itself?)

Comment: Security is not an issue for me in my case. I have updated my question, since I found much better solution, but not optimal in my view.